getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail returning "An error has occurred"
The HTTP request for getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail is failing with message "unknown error: an error has occurred" in Graph Explorer, Postman, and PowerShell.
Using the HTTP request and changing the period/date and 1.0/beta has no effect.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(period='D7')
Even using the Powershell SDK of Get-MgReportTeamUserActivityUserDetail is returning the same error code.image
